# I want a rich text editor for make text bold, italic and some file attachment

Tags: flutter, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I need a text editor which I can edit for some modifications because of requirement. My basic need is bold, italic, underline, image and video attachment.

Comment: Have you looked on https://pub.dev ?

Comment: Yes, I have seen zefyr in pub.dev but can we upgrade this library as per our need. Do you have suggestion for any other library?

Comment: You can make your own fork, makes changes to the package then add your fork as a dependency in the pubspec file.